# Why two 不 in 不得不, when only one "not" in its English translations?

Tags: negation

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=%E4%B8%8D%E5%BE%97%E4%B8%8D) and [ZDIC](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%8D%E5%BE%97%E4%B8%8D) translate 不得不 as

> have no choice or option but to, cannot but, ***have to***, can't help it, can't avoid

"***Have to***" contains no negator particles!  All other translations have merely one negator, either "no" or "not"! Thus why does Chinese have two negators in 不得不?

Comment: This reminds me of "No can do"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "have to" contains no negator particles! All other translations have merely 1 negator, either "no" or "not"! Thus why does Chinese have 2 negators in 不得不?

"不得不" is another way to say "一定要" (certainly have to)

*要 has the meaning of "have to"*

"不得" is a tightly bonded term that we treat like a compound word, which means "not allow/ cannot" in Chinese. e.g. 不得進入 (not allow to enter)

You can see 不得 as the literal form of 不可以 (can't/ not allow)

"不得不" (cannot not to) = not allowed to not" -- It means the same as 一定要(certainly have to) in which 一定 is a compound word

Although "不得不" (not allow not to)  means the same as "一定要" (certainly have to/ must),  "不得不" emphasizes the 'no choice' aspect more

**Edit:**

IONQ wrote

> *Thanks. ""不得不" (cannot not to) = not allowed to not" -- It means the same as 一定要(certainly have to) in which 一定 is a compound word" Can you pls elaborate? How do they mean the same?*

I should say they mean the same by logical deduction.

- If you are not allowed to not do something, then it is something you must do.
- If you must do something, then you are not allowed to not doing it

Example:

**不得不**去 (**not allowed to not** go) = **一定要**去 (**must** go)

Comment: Thanks. ""不得不" (cannot not to) = not allowed to not" -- It means the same as 一定要(certainly have to) in which 一定 is a compound word" Can you pls elaborate? How do they mean the same?

Comment: Can you pls edit your answer, rather than reply as a comment? Comments can be deleted.

Comment: @IONQ See my edition at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

On the English side, please note that:

1. Negation is implied in the preposition "**but**":

> have **no** choice or option **but** to,
> can**not** **but**,
> ca**n't** help it (**but**)

2. Negation is implied in the verb **avoid**:

> ca**n't** **avoid**

3. Two negations equal to **affirmation**:

> have to

Answer (score 1):

You can split 不得不 to 不得 and 不.

不得 means "no choice", "must not".

So 不得不 means "only one choice", "must".

Comment: Can you pls elaborate? How does "So 不得不 means "only one choice", "must""???

Comment: Can you pls edit your answer, rather than reply as a comment?